# Can there be different numbers of objects in the collections of the views?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Something I've been wondering, can you have a different number of objects for each view when querying the metadata properties? (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/). From the autocad perspective, there seem to be only two categories, 2d views and 3d views and any named views won't get their own metadata-guid, so no (btw how to get access to those named views? see attachment). But views from revit get their own metadata-guid per view, from testing I've gotten a View with an empty collection. Is it safe to assume that the {3D} view from Revit always contain all objects? Same for Civil3d/Autocad?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot expect that Revit 3D views contain all objects since the user might hide some objects or turn-off their visibilities in the views, and the Revit translator will only export visible objects in the 3D view in Revit vies to Forge views (also called viewables).

**Update 2020-01-13:**

After checking our engineering team and my investigations, you have to set that layer's plot property to off in the layer manager to tell AutoCAD translator not to translate that layer, then the layer will not visible in the 2D view of the Forge Viewer forever.

In the AutoCAD:
[image]

In the Forge Viewer:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @eason-kang! Some follow up questions:
1. So any user-hidden objects, can never be shown in the Forge viewer?
2. Does this work similarly in AutoCAD/Civil3D?

Comment: @jorisjh For q1, I sorry to say yea. Unless the objects are visible in the Revit view, it will never appear in Forge Viewer view. For the q2, I should be similar.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know! I might have to look into a pre-processing step in design automation because we are looking to extract data from all objects in property sets, which does not work if users hide some objects.

Comment: Tested this with Revit and I see what you mean. Can't really reproduce this with Civil3d though, objects on hidden layers are exported and can be made visible by layer again.

Comment: How did you hide the Civil3d object? Turn the object off by layers is the only way as I know. With my test, `isolate > hide objects` is not supported, since it hides objects temporarily only. While reopening the DWG with AutoCAD again, the hidden objects are shown again. (I didn't have it installed on my PC, but I tested it with AutoCAD instead.)

Comment: I tried both methods, indeed as you say `isolate > hide objects` is temporary. I tried a layer with an object that's frozen and turned off, in layers in the viewer you can toggle it on and off and the object is processed in properties.
https://gfycat.com/quaintfittingkitten

Comment: Oh, my apologies, Thank you for pointing out. I'm not aware of that. My Revit knowledge is better than AutoCAD. I'm double-checking the hiding object behavior of the AutoCAD/Civil3D with our engineering team, will get back A.S.A.P. Thanks!

Comment: @jorisjh I have updated my answer above, please have a try, Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! That's really helpful, now I know what to tell our partners *not to do* if they want to get all data across.